# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'Flag'

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, nlp

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run_summarization.py", line 327, in 
`tf.app.run()`
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 126, in run `_sys.exit(main(argv))`
  File "run_summarization.py", line 306, in main
`batcher = Batcher(FLAGS.data_path, vocab, hps, single_pass=FLAGS.single_pass)`
  File "/home/hdm/hdm/program/CNN/pointer-generator-master/batcher.py", line 238, in **init**
`self._example_queue = Queue.Queue(self.BATCH_QUEUE_MAX * self._hps.batch_size)`
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'Flag'

Answer (score 5):

In `run_summarization.py` around line 297

Change :

```
for key,val in FLAGS.__flags.iteritems()
```

To :

```
for key,val in FLAGS.flag_values_dict().iteritems()
```

For Python 3 change to :

```
for key,val in FLAGS.flag_values_dict().items()
```

Answer (score 2):

Find:

```
for key,val in FLAGS.__flags.iteritems(): # for each flag
    if key in hparam_list: # if it's in the list
        hps_dict[key] = val # add it to the dict
```

should start from line: 297*

Change:

```
for key,val in FLAGS.__flags.iteritems()
```

to:

```
for key,val in FLAGS.flag_values_dict().iteritems()
```

Comment: "dict" object has no attribute "iteritems"